# Is there a way to REQUIRE derived classes be sealed in C#?

Tags: c#

I am creating *pseudo*-value type classes to avoid aliasing issues, but implementing the overrides for `Equals(object)`, `Equals(Type)`, `GetHashCode()`, as well as the `==` and `!=` operators over and over got me thinking about refactoring it into an abstract base class.

Since these are going to be "value" types, I want the derived classes to be `sealed`.

My current implementation throws an `Exception` in the `abstract` base class constructor if the derived class is not `sealed`:

```
namespace SomeNamespace
{
    public abstract class ValueType
    {
        private bool DerivedTypeIsSealed => 
            (GetType().Attributes & TypeAttributes.Sealed) != 0;

        protected ValueType()
        {
            if (!DerivedTypeIsSealed)
            { throw new UnsealedDerivedTypeException(
               $"All types deriving from {nameof(ValueType)} must be sealed"); }
        }

        protected abstract int GetHashCodeFunction();

        public override int GetHashCode() => GetHashCodeFunction();
        public override bool Equals(object other)
        {
            return other != null &&
                   GetHashCode() == other.GetHashCode();
        }
        public static bool operator ==(ValueType left, ValueType right)
        {
            return left is null && right is null ||
                   !(left is null) && left.Equals(right);
        }
        public static bool operator !=(ValueType left, ValueType right) =>
            !(left == right);
    }
}
```

... but that seems a bit late in the game.

Is there some way to declare an abstract base class *so that the pre-compiler (for lack of a better word) will complain with red squigglies* when I try to declare a derived class that isn't `sealed`?  Something along the lines of how I can restrict `T` to be only a `class` in `AbstractClass<T> where T : class`

Comment: To create a value type, you need to define your type as a struct (as opposed to a class, which defines a reference type). since structs have no inheritance then the statement `Since these are going to be "value" types, I want the derived classes to be sealed` is moot

Comment: Yes, but the whole point of this exercise is to create a base type and not have to duplicate all the code above for every type.

Comment: You can't have all your wishes come true unfortunately

Comment: Ahh yeah, that too

Comment: I'm not sure it's a great idea to implement Equals in terms of GetHashCode. Unequal objects can have identical hashcodes.

Comment: @lesscode Oh, damn - good point!  I'll have to change that.

Comment: Also, it's usually the case that Equals incorporates a type compatibility check. Without this, objects of two types that are otherwise completely incompatible might be regarded to have equality. Do you really have a use case that allows for this?

Comment: So you're back to having to implement GetHashCode and Equals for all your types anyway. Now you have to consider mutability: if your objects are mutable it's not a great idea to override == to provide value equality semantics.

Comment: And having the operators in the base class means that two completely different value types can now be compared for equality when they wouldn't be if the operators are only defined in each value type separately. Basically, this base class can't do anything useful without opening up more opportunities for people to write wrong code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no construct in the C# language itself to control the derived class in that way. You could 'enforce' it in the way that you have shown by examining the derived class, but I don't think that would be a good approach.

I would instead ask what the motivation is for preventing a derived class from being further derived. From what you have described so far, I don't see any problem with allowing the derived classes to be further derived. Perhaps if you can expand on what you are trying to prevent, I or someone else can suggest how to achieve your goal.

Comment: One reason to prevent derivation is equality.  Each class declares its own definition of `GetHashCode()` and `Equals()` - but when you start deriving types then your equality conditions might return true when they really aren't... and yeah, I agree that the `Exception` is not the way to go.

Comment: Would it suffice to just seal the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods? In your class, you can define them with the `sealed` modifier such that the derived class cannot override them.